# Promise.all invoking array variable full of functions

Tags: javascript

```js
function getMyFunction(data) {
    return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value:' + data);
    });
}
const whatToGet = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e',
];
const stuffArray = whatToGet.map(thing => getMyFunction(thing));
Promise.all(stuffArray).then((result) => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
});
```

I am expecting

```
result: [
    'here is the value: a',
    'here is the value: b',
    'here is the value: c',
    'here is the value: d',
    'here is the value: e'
]
```

but I instead get result:

```
result:  [ () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value:', data);
    }), () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value:', data);
    }), () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value:', data);
    }), () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value:', data);
    }), () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value:', data);
    })
]
```

Comment: You just asked basically the same question and got an appropriate answer

Comment: @charlietfl Completely different question.

Comment: no it's not...the basics are exactly the same except instead of passing  one function you return an array of functions...that all need to be invoked or as others suggest just return the promise

Comment: to be honest the function seems redundant....would not perhaps have been considered the same question though if you had asked exactly what you asked in last comment...and linked to other question. Or simply asked the original answerer for help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Promise.all(stuffArray).then((result) => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
});
```

Use:

```
Promise.all(stuffArray.map(func => func())).then((result) => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an array of functions into `Promise.all`, but it expects an array of promises.

Unless there is a reason you want to produce a bunch of functions that you have to then execute, it would be simpler to just produce promises instead:

```
function getMyPromise(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value:' + data);
    });
}
```

Then this should work fine:

```
const stuffArray = whatToGet.map(getMyPromise);
Promise.all(stuffArray).then((result) => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
});
```

Side note/protip: don't use `new Promise` if you want to create a promise for a specific value. Just use `Promise.resolve`:

```
function getMyPromise(data) {
    return Promise.resolve('here is the value:' + data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you expect this result then make sure that you are calling the promises:

```
const stuffArray = whatToGet.map(thing => getMyFunction(thing)());
```

Notice: `getMyFunction(thing)()` where we are actually calling the returned anonymous function from `getMyFunction` in order to reach out to the actual promise.

Alternatively if you want to use your current code then make sure that `getMyFunction` returns a promise and not a function that returns a promise:

```
function getMyFunction(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value:' + data);
    });
}
```